# Delete all data before two months from table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a SQL Server job which will execute each month and will remove all old records except last two months data. My ultimate motive is to keep only last 2 months data in my database when job executes, irrespective of whether the months are 28, 30 or 31 day month.

For example, if the job is executed on 1st of March, I want all the records starting from 1st January to 1st March in my current database and rest all records removed.

Currently I am using the following SQL query for selecting data to remove.

```
SELECT *  
  FROM tbl
  where [Datetime] <= DATEADD(MONTH, -2,convert(datetime,'03/02/2016')  )
```

Note: the date format is "MM/dd/yyyy" but it selects the data of 1st Jan also. It's not fixed to execute job on 1st of each month. If I take date as '03/01/2016' then the output is good.

Well I am going to use following where clause

```
where [Datetime] <= DATEADD(MONTH, -2,Getdate())
```

so consider that the date can be any date of march (or date of any month).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @requiredDate datetime
SELECT @requiredDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0)) 

SELECT *  
  FROM tbl
  where [Datetime] < @requiredDate
```

Comment: The OP also wants the 1st of the current month it's ran, `5/1/2016` in the case of your code, so you need to add one day so the `SELECT` will not drop any rows that have a [DateTime] of `5/1/2016 03:31:56` for example. Using `<=` won't work unless you add 23:59:59 to @requiredDate. `SELECT @requiredDate = DATEADD(day,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0)))`